# Jump discontinuity is not a Lebesgue point

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be locally integrable, then for $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\lim\limits_{R\to 0}\frac{1}{|B_R(x_0)|}\int\limits_{B_R(x_0)}|f(x)-f(x_0)|dx=0.$$
The point $x_0$ is called Lebesgue point of $f$. Show that:

at $x_0$ has $f$ a jump discontinuity $\Rightarrow$ $x_0$ is not a Lebesgue point

This means that $\lim\limits_{x\uparrow x_0} f(x)\neq \lim\limits_{x\downarrow x_0} f(x)$. If $R$ is small than $B_R(x_0)$ contains either $\lim\limits_{x\uparrow x_0} f(x)$ or $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow x_0} f(x)$. So intuitively it is clear, but I do not know how to write it down.

Comment: Split the integral into two parts, $[x_0-R,x_0)$ and $[x_0,x_0+R]$. Use the existence of the one-sided limits to estimate the integrals.